# Create a QByteArray from a QImage and vice-versa

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qbytearray

I need to encode an already-created QImage into a QByteArray to send to a socket, and decode it on the another side.

On the server side, I'm trying to do something like:

```
// The vector is mandatory. The class that creates the image line expects it.

QVector<unsigned char> msg;  
QImage line(create_image_line(msg));

QByteArray ba((char*)line.bits(), line.numBytes());
for (int i = 0; i < ba.size(); ++i) {
  msg.append(ba[i]);
}

send_msg(msg);
```

The create_image_line does something like:

```
... handle the msg and get the image properties...
QImage img(pixels_, 1, QImage::Format_RGB32);
... set the values ...
return(img);
```

And on the client side:

```
receive_msg(msg);
QByteArray ba;
for (int i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i) {
  ba.append(msg[i]);
}

QImage line(LINE_WIDTH, 1, QImage::Format_RGB32);
line.fromData(ba);
```

Something goes wrong, and the image is shown with a lot of noise (I know that the problem is located in this conversion, due another successful tests).

I'd like to know where is the problem.

Rgds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QImage::fromData` does not retain the format, it tries to probe for a file header. It's also a static function, so it does not modify line (which stays uninitialized), it returns an image (which you discard). And it's concent of format is things like `PNG` or `JPG`, not pixel formats like the constructor.

So to do the way you have it now, you need to loop through line.bits again copying in the pixels.

However, [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html) can serialize most of the Qt value types, [including QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#operator-lt-lt-162). If you're in control of both ends and open to changing the protocol, this is probably a much simpler and robust solution.